# display connection result on another page

Tags: php, mysql

Answers here talk about search results. my problem is the connection status of mysql being displayed on another page when i click submit button of a form.

i have tried placing the connection code in different places in the code.but no success.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","ahmedinho","ahmedinho");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}



<form action="result.php" method="post" id="testing">
Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="name">
<br>
E-mail: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email">
<br>
Address:  <input type="text" name="address">
<br>
Phone: &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="number" name="phone">
<br><br>
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
<br><br>
<input type="submit" form="testing" name="submit" value="submit" >
</form> 

$sql="CREATE DATABASE phpmysql";
if {(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    { echo "Database phpymsql created successfully"; }
else { echo "Error creating database"; . mysqli_error($con); }

mysqli_close($con);
?>

'''' 

RESULT PAGE
...........
```

**i expected:**

> Database phpymsql created successfully" to be displayed on result.php
>   page. instead,nothing about the connection is displayed.

Comment: What's up with the braces before the `if {`? Is your error reporting enabled?

Comment: What you have shown here will not begin to execute in PHP. It is full of errors. You need to start with something a lot simpler and make sure you know how to find the errors PHP is already telling you about.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brace after your 'if' and remove the semicolon after "Error Creating database".

Should be something like:

```
$sql="CREATE DATABASE phpmysql";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    { echo "Database phpymsql created successfully"; }
else { echo "Error creating database" . mysqli_error($con); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I made the { and  . Correction. 
Was supposed to put the connection code on result.php instead of mysqlpr.php, which was the page containing the form.